# AAC extradata and extradata_size is not sent over UDP

Tags: ffmpeg, aac, adts

I am using below command to transcode audio from static file which contains extradata.

```
./ffmpeg -re -y -loglevel info -loglevel verbose -err_detect careful -f mpegts -i <ts_file_path> -c:v copy -c:a aac -f mpegts "udp://127.0.0.1:2567"
```

When I run below command, I do not get the extradata_size always it is 0 (zero)

```
./ffmpeg -re -y -loglevel error -err_detect careful -analyzeduration 8000000 -probesize 4000000 -rtbufsize 300000 -flush_packets 0 -fflags +genpts+discardcorrupt -max_delay 200000 -f mpegts -timeout 30000000 -i "udp://127.0.0.1:2567?fifo_size=50000000&overrun_nonfatal=1&buffer_size=50000000" -c copy  -ignore_unknown -f hls -hls_playlist_type 0 -flags global_header -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 30 -hls_flags delete_segments  <m3u8_file_path>
```

Am I missing anything here?
Thank you.

Comment: I’m not sure what you think extradata is. It’s not arburtuarry data. It is codec specific headers. Mpegts uses ADTS headers before ever aac frame instead of out of band initialization data.

Comment: I am naive, but surely extradata is passed and after some more, debugging and find that the extradata is written when <m3u8_file_path> replaced by <filename>, so my question is when m3u8 file is present and segmenting happens this extradata has to be passed to each segment. Am I right?

Comment: example command : 
`./ffmpeg -re -y -loglevel error -err_detect careful -analyzeduration 8000000 -probesize 4000000 -rtbufsize 300000 -flush_packets 0 -fflags +genpts+discardcorrupt -max_delay 200000 -f mpegts -timeout 30000000 -i "udp://127.0.0.1:2567?fifo_size=50000000&overrun_nonfatal=1&buffer_size=50000000" -c copy  -ignore_unknown -f hls -hls_playlist_type 0 -flags global_header -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 30 -hls_flags delete_segments mpegts`

Comment: note that the VIDEO extradata_size is valid but not the AUDIO extradata_size.

Comment: In mpegts the extradata is in band, part of the frame.